# Code First and Existing Database with Data

Tags: ef-code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing a windows application which uses SQL Server Database. I have different versions of this application and they have different database structure, so I need to migrate database to the latest version on application start. I want to compare the database structure with the application model, then do alter, create or drop commands.

Also I want to use EF Code-First ORM, after some search I've figured it out that there are some useful commands and configs in code first. But the problem is, as I know, all of them drop the existing database and create a new one so the data will be lost while I need the data.

I used these lines in my application start function:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
migrator.Update();
```

But after execution this line I will get this exception:

```
There is already an object named 'SomeTable' in the database.
```

I know that, it's right and there is that table but in structure is changed! How can I compare the structure and do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

That's not [how migrations work.](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/ef/migrations-under-the-hood) You need a migration for every version of your database so EF can check the __MigrationHistory table and see if it has been applied. If your initializer is set to [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx) your database won't be recreated on model changes.

You could try to recreate the history: roll back to your oldest database, add a migration, add 2nd oldest version changes, create a 2nd migration, etc.

Another option is to add a migration for where you are now, generate a script (update-database -Script) then comment out the stuff that exists in each deployed database before applying it.

Yet another option would be to use the [VS Schema compare utility](http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/schema-compare-for-sql-server-in-visual-studio-2013/) against each database and your current database to get the changes over. Then apply a baseline migration to each (add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges).

Now moving forward you can generate a series of migrations and your code should work as expected.